# Replace null in a column of a dataframe with other value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset` like the following

```
monthYear    code
201601       11
201601       12
201601       12
201601       10
201602       null
201602       21
201602       21
201602       21
201603       null
```

When `code` is `null` I want to replace that with the `code` that appeared the most during the last month. For the above example, the first `null` will get replaced by `12` and the second one with `21`.

So the result would be the following.

```
monthYear    code
201601       11
201601       12
201601       12
201601       10
201602       12
201602       21
201602       21
201602       21
201603       21
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fill transformation of Class DataFrameNaFunctions https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameNaFunctions.html#fill(double)

where you replace null or NaN values in the Dataframes

Example

```
val df = spark.read.json("../test.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string]

scala> df.show
+----+----+
| age|name|
+----+----+
|  12| xyz|
|null| abc|
+----+----+

df.na.fill(0, Seq("age"))

res3.show
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 12| xyz|
|  0| abc|
+---+----+
```

Again, if you want replace value of this column

with `res3.na.replace("age",Map(0 -> 51))`

But Again it will not replace with different values you have to do it something on the source side

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the max with a window function and coalesce to get what you want.

Let us assume df is a dataframe(variable) that contains the table you showed,

```
df = df.selectExpr("*","count(code) over (partition by monthYear) as code_count")
df = df.selectExpr("*","rank(code) over (partition by monthYear order by code_count) as max_code")
df = df.selectExpr("*","coalesce(code,max_code) as code_new")
```

Would give you what you are looking for.